# Why is Google Backup and Sync exchanging files bidirectionally instead of unidirectionally?

Tags: backup, google-apps

Everything was fine until I uninstalled Google Backup and Sync in favor of Dropbox Plus (what a mistake!). I ended up actually restoring my entire internal flash drive from a backup, which I thought would restore GB&S to normal functioning, but ever since then, when I launch GB&S and configure it to back up my Desktop and Documents folders on "My Laptop" to the "Computer" tab in Google Drive, it asks me if I want to merge files from my local Desktop and Documents folders with those in my laptop as it appears in the "Computers" section of Google Drive. I thought it meant unidirectionally (i.e. backup), but what happens is that GB&S starts *downloading* stuff that was deleted long ago! If I cancel the merge requests, GB&S basically stops.

Is there any way to insure unidirectional backup?

Comment: It probably doesn't consider the restore to be the same Mac. I've seen Backblaze do this too, but it warns you & gives you a link to tel it it made a mistake. idk GB&S though, or how to tell it the same thing. It will be at Google's end though, not local.

Comment: How does that explain the downloading? More importantly, is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I wound up deleting my computer and all documents from the "Computer" tab in Google Drive, and backing up everything again. So far so good.